# Make Shinydashboard sidebar fixed

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

Below is a screenshot of my shiny dashboard. I'd like the sidebar (where there is a search function) to be fixed such that when a user loads it, It doesn't collapse.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide code to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `collapsed = FALSE` to `dashboardSidebar`

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
        

        # Dashboard Title
        title = "DashboardPage",
        
        # Dashboard Header;
        header = dashboardHeader(
                
        ),
        
        # Dashboard Sidebar; 
        sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
                collapsed = FALSE
                ),
        
        # Dashboard Body;
        body = dashboardBody(
                
        )
)
```